# How to calculate the max result size of Spark Driver

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Recently I got an error that "spark.driver.MaxResultSize" was exceeded. I am using pyspark on yarn client mode. The code is to generate random fake data for testing.

```
new_df = None
for i in range(int(2000)):
    df = spark.range(0,10000)
    temp = df.select(f.col("id").alias('user_id'), f.round(1000 * f.abs(f.randn(seed=27))).alias("duration"))
    if new_df is None:
        new_df = temp
    else:
        new_df = new_df.union(temp)
```

I tried to increase the max result size to 15G to make it work. I am not sure why it required so much memory. Is there any guide on how to calculate the size of the result set?

Comment: Any value in the answer you think?

Answer (score 1):

The code is all being executed on the driver - not the worker(s) is my impression. e.g. the for and the df statement. Different to say reading from Hive or JDBC via DFReader.

The docs state:

> spark.driver.maxResultSize    1g default  Limit of total size of serialized
>   results of all partitions for each Spark action (e.g. collect) in
>   bytes. Should be at least 1M, or 0 for unlimited. Jobs will be aborted
>   if the total size is above this limit. Having a high limit may cause
>   out-of-memory errors in driver (depends on spark.driver.memory and
>   memory overhead of objects in JVM). Setting a proper limit can protect
>   the driver from out-of-memory errors.

You might want to look at these for guidance: [How to use spark to generate huge amount of random integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069080/how-to-use-spark-to-generate-huge-amount-of-random-integers) and [how to make rdd tuple list in spark？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902411/how-to-make-rdd-tuple-list-in-spark) so as to distribute the load processing as well as increase spark.driver.maxResultSize if you wish to collect to the driver - which I would not.